# Conversion of 16 bit value to 32 bit value in C++

Tags: c++

Which is the most effective way to convert 16 bit value to 32 bit value in C++ by padding extra 2 bytes with 0 (i.e. without changing value but only change in size of variable).

Comment: You'd have to ask each type of CPU that question. C++ sits between you and it, so you needn't concern yourself with such useless trivia.

Comment: If you definitively want zero padding, you need to reinterpret the 16-bit value as an `unsigned short` and then assign that to a 32-bit value.  If you don't use the cast, you'll get 1 bits as padding for negative 16-bit values, and 0 bits as padding for positive values.  There are other caveats (`unsigned short` might not be a 16-bit value), but they're not common problems.

Comment: You should use standard fixed-sized integer types, like `uint16_t` and `uint32_t`

Comment: Is the original value signed or unsigned?

Comment: The most effective way is to simply assign the 16 bit value to the 32 bit variable. The compiler will make sure that the fastest code is generated

Comment: when assigning 16 bit to 32 bit variable, is compiler sets extra bytes to zero? Original value is unsigned.

Comment: Please show declaration, definition and initialisation of both variables in a code example.

Comment: Can any one explain how this works in variadic argumunets of a function. I need to convert size of all arguments of variadic arguments to 32 bit.

Comment: @TiYan It is good that you are caring about the efficiency of your code. However, your question shows a severe lack of research on your part. Much of the questions you are asking can be easily searched on the internet. Also, it would be much more effective for you to understand the language this way.

Comment: @JayWaiTan Ok, Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Include the `<cstdint>` header and initialize your 32-bit integer with your 16-bit value. Be sure to pay attention to your signs. In the example below I'm converting all integer values (signed or not) to an unsigned 32-bit integer.

### Example Conversion

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void dumpVar(const uint32_t value)
{
    cout << setfill('0') << setw(8) << hex << value << endl;
}

int main()
{
   uint16_t test1 = 0xffff;
   int16_t  test2 = 32767;
   uint16_t test3 = 0xf33e;
   int16_t  test4 = -32768;
   dumpVar(test1);
   dumpVar(test2);
   dumpVar(test3);
   dumpVar(test4);

   return 0;
}
```

### Sample Output

Notice how negative numbers aren't zero-padded like you might expect. This is just a function of the sign bit.

```
0000ffff
00007fff
0000f33e
ffff8000
```

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ handle this sort of operation automatically.

For example:

```
short small_number = 0xbeef;
int large_number = small_number;

// large_number is now 0x0000beef
```